# Set Theory: Prove if $A \Delta C=B \Delta C$ then $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had this question and this is how I tried to approach it:
Let $x \in A \Delta C$, therefore $x \in B \Delta C$ by assumption.

$x \in A$ and $x \notin C$ or $x \in C$ and $x \notin A$, and also, $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$ or $x \in C$ and $x \notin B$.

If $x \in C$, then $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$.

If $x \notin C$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Is that enough to prove $A=B$? I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do proof by inclusion you should take your $x$ to be in $A$ and then show it is in $B$; and then the reverse inclusion (though the argument for $x\in B$ implies $x\in A$ should be symmetrical to the other one).  Also if you know algebraic properties of the symmetric difference operator, that might give another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A$.

Either $x\in C$, then $x \notin A {\tiny{\triangle}}C$, thus by hypothesis $x \notin B {\tiny{\triangle}}C$, and since $x\in C$ what follows is that $x\in B$.

Or $x\notin C$, then $x \in A {\tiny{\triangle}}C$ and thus $x\in B {\tiny{\triangle}}C$, and since $x\notin C$ what follows is that $x\in B$.

Therefore $A\subset B$ and since $A$ and $B$ play a symmetrical role, we get $A=B$.